# Hosting subdomains separately with and without SSL while using a wildcard certificate

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, dns, subdomain, wildcard

I'm having a strange problem with a separately hosted subdomain I have. I'm running an application on Engine Yard, let's call it mysite.com. I have a wildcard SSL certificate installed there which covers all the subdomains (things like api.mysite.com). We recently decided to migrate our blog to be hosted independently (right now it lives on wordpress.com). Because I can't run the blog alongside our Rails app with ease on Engine Yard, I decided to grab some cheap hosting space from Dreamhost to host our Wordpress blog there. I set up the server there to fully host our subdomain (let's call it blog.mysite.com), and updated the DNS A record on Hover (our DNS provider) to point blog.mysite.com to the Dreamhost server. So here's the issue:

If I go to blog.mysite.com via Firefox or Safari on my Mac I see the basic Wordpress install which I set up. However, if I try to view things with Chrome I get the following error:

This webpage is not available
Error 118 (net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT): The operation timed out.

This happens on all Macs running Chrome I could get my hands on. I tried both clearing the cache and flushing the DNS but nothing. The weirdest part is Chrome keeps looking for https://blog.mysite.com instead of http://blog.mysite.com. There is no SSL cert installed on the subdomain for the blog on Dreamhost because it's not necessary.

Has anyone ever come across this before? And in case anyone wants to try the actual address is http://blog.frestyl.com.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you have a 301 permanent redirect that Chrome registered http://blog.frestyl.com -> https://blog.frestyl.com. Besides clearing the cache I'm not sure what else can be done.